Having problems with PowerShell
Anyone know how to open a directory in the PowerShell console so that I can find how many things are in my downloads file.
I tried to type "dir" however, It did not give me what I was looking for. I wanted to find how many things I have in my downloads file.

Try dir ~\Downloads |Measure-Object 

Welcome to SO! You should have been able to google this...
#Count files in the downloads, your path may differ
PS> (GCI -Path G:\BEKDocs\Downloads\*.*).count
6

#Count only files in a network directory
PS> (GCI -Path "\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\NAS-Downloads\*.*" -File).count
3

#Count only files in spcified directory and all child directories
PS> (GCI -Path "\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\NAS-Downloads\*.*" -File -Recurse).count
342

